# How do I prove the inequality?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, projection

Say that $y:=$ argmin$_{x\in C} \frac{1}{2}||x||^2_2$.

$C$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in Euclidean n-space.

How would I go about to show the following statement for any $x\in C$?
$$||x-y||^2_2 \leq ||x||^2_2 - ||y||^2_2$$

It is obvious that $||x||^2_2 \ge ||y||^2_2$ but I just can't think of how I would incorporate the first term of the inequality.
I have tried to approach it as a projection of the origin onto $C$ but I'm not even sure if that is the right way to approach it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Edit: Clarifications on set $C$

Comment: What is $C$ and what's the definition of $|| \cdot ||^2_2$? (I think $C$ stands for the set of complex numbers and $|| \cdot ||^2_2$ is the $\mathcal{l}^2$-norm. Is my assumption correct?)

Comment: $C$ is just any given set and yes it is the $l2$ norm squared

Comment: @mellowtoast The $\ell^2$ norm doesn't make sense on just "any given set". It must be a subset of some space where the $\ell^2$ norm makes sense. Is it $\Bbb{C}$, as tommyinnit09 suggests? Is it $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or $\Bbb{C}^n$) for some $n$? Or are we dealing with the infinite-dimensional $\ell^2$ space over $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the clarification question. $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in euclidean n-space. Hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now, the proposition in this question is not actually true. For example, if we consider $C = \{-1, 2\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, then $y = -1$. If we take $x = 2$, then $\|x - y\|_2^2 = |2 - (-1)|^2 = 9$, but $\|x\|_2^2 - \|y\|_2^2 = |2|^2 - |{-1}|^2 = 3$. Are there any other assumptions on $C$ that the question is missing?

Comment: The set $C$ is a convex set so the values would be continuous. Would the proposition hold true in this case?

Comment: @mellowtoast Yes, I believe so. Could you please edit these pieces of information ($C$ is convex and a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$) into your question? They are vital to understanding it properly, and should be visible in the body of the question. After that, I'll work on an answer.

Comment: Edited the question! I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The vector $y$ is the projection of $0$ onto $C$, and fortunately, for convex sets, we have a nice characterisation of when a vector is a projection onto convex $C$. Specifically, $y \in C$ is the projection of a point $z$ onto $C$ if and only if
$$\forall x \in C, \langle z - y, x - y \rangle \le 0.$$
In this case, $z = 0$, so we have
$$\forall x \in C, \langle y, x - y \rangle \ge 0.$$
Therefore, assuming $x \in C$,
\begin{align*}
&\|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 - \|x - y\|^2 \\
=\; &\|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 + 2\langle x, y \rangle \\
=\; &2\langle x, y \rangle - 2\|y\|^2 \\
=\; &2\langle x - y, y \rangle \ge 0,
\end{align*}
so
$$\|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 \ge \|x - y\|^2$$
for any $x \in C$.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. I did think about the approach from the projection of the origin but didn't think to try and solve it from the results up. Really grateful for he help!

Comment: No problem! In future, I would mention in the question that you had thought about this approach, and show us where you got stuck. The more information you put about your thoughts and attempts into a question, the better it will be received. Anyway, welcome to MSE!